# Сохранить ответ с ожидаемым результатом JMETER

Tags: jmeter, response, assertion

Я получаю "result:0" в некоторых запросах, используя Response Assertion, я могу посмотреть в каких командах это происходит. Как мне сделать, так чтобы автоматически записывался весь ответ.
Пример ответа: {"errors":[{"errCategory":-1,"errReason":"Невозможно получить из реестра ошибок параметр "Причина возникновения"","errRecommend":"Невозможно получить из реестра ошибок параметр "Рекомендации для пользователя"","errStatus":"Невозможно получить из реестра ошибок параметр "Статус"","errTechRecommend":"Невозможно получить из реестра ошибок параметр "Рекомендации технические"","errText":"Невозможно получить из реестра ошибок параметр "Ошибка"","errorCode":"090.090.00001","isVisible":0}],"result":0}

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) в ваш Test Plan, например [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) и настройте его примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В случае если сэмплер будет с ошибкой Listener сохранит ответ сервера в файл errors.xml, после того как тест будет закончен ответы можно будет посмотреть с помощью [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

Чуть более подробную информацию можно найти в статье [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter)